# Saving precalculated and calculated data VS precalculated data and calculating them upon retrieval

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am new in designing databases, I have tables that has a lot of calculated data.

Labor Table

```
table columns | formula

labor_code
job_desc
hourly_wage
daily_wage = hourly_wage * 8
monthly_wage = hourly_wage * 208
benefit_1 = daily * ( 5/12)
benefit_2 = monthly_wage / 12
benefit_3 = there is a range of monthly_wage for a specific value to this
benefit_4 = value given by the user
benefit_5 = value given by the user
total_hourly_rate = hourly_wage + benefit_(1-5)
total_daily_rate = total_hourly_rate * 8
total_monthly_rate = total_hourly_rate * 208
```

Material Table

```
table columns | formula

material_code
material_desc
brand
unit
base_price = user input
hauling_cost = user input
labor_code
labor_type = its either ful or basic
labor_rate = if labor type == ful ? labor_rate = labor.hourly_wage : labor.total_hourly_rate 
total_price = base_price + hauling_cost + labor_rate
```

given the table above the future specs of the application which will also have tables and computed data will base on the values above.

**I want to know which is the better approach save all the data ( including the computed data ) to the database or should I just save the precalculated data and calculated data ( i.e total_hourly_rate )  programmatically after retrieving the data?**

If my question is not clear please comment so I can clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we're really talking about here is *caching* the result of calculations. Because, you see, one of the trade-offs you don't make mention of in your post is that, e.g., every time you have to update `hourly_wage` you also have to update `daily_wage` and `monthly_wage` because they are derivative.

So what this really comes down to is probably something you must answer for yourself:

- Do I want **database writes** to be more expensive?

**-- OR --**

- Do I want **application runtime** to be more expensive?

(I say "application runtime" because it's not clear from your question what your application layer looks like, i.e. what will finally use the results of these calculations.)

You want database writes to be more expensive when application runtime is mission critical, e.g. a high-load webserver where most of the database operations are **reads**.

You want application runtime to be more expensive when it doesn't need to be extremely optimized or when database space is at a premium. The calculations in your particular use case don't take much time (just simple multiplication and division after all) but could definitely increase page load times if this were a webapp.

Then again, if it's a webapp, there's probably better caching options available to you than this which you have to maintain yourself.

Comment: Sorry for a noob question but what is caching the calculation in detail?

Comment: Caching is just a fancy word for "saving" in this context, specifically with an aim toward trading space (to store the result) for time (to calculate the result).

Answer (score 0):

Since calculation is very cheap, it's unlikely the increased storage required for caching its result will be worth it.

Yes, storage is cheap these days, but *that's not the point* - "fatter" data means slower I/O, and I/O tends to be the main bottleneck when it comes to database performance.